# Use two for loops simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists which have unknown number of elements. One list containing names and another castes

'''Like This'''

```
names = ['name1','name2',........'name99'] 
castes = ['cast1','cast2',........'cast99']
```

And i want print like this:

```
Hello Name1 cast1.
Hello Name2 Cast2.
.
.
.
.
.
Hello Name99 Cast99
```

I have tried this but it doesnot work.

```
for i in names:
   for j in castes:
      print('Hello '+ i + j)
```

But it prints randomly. like...

```
Hello Name1 Cast1
Hello Name1 Cast2
.
.
Hello Name1 Cast99
.
.
.
Hello Name2 Cast1
Hello Name2 Cast2
.
.
Hello Name3 Cast99
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) builtin will do what you want,
combining lists that have corresponding elements.

```
>>> names = 'n1 n2 n3 n4'.split()
>>> castes = 'c1 c2 c3 c4'.split()
>>> pprint.pprint(list(zip(names, castes)), width=20)
[('n1', 'c1'),
 ('n2', 'c2'),
 ('n3', 'c3'),
 ('n4', 'c4')]
```

From there you can finesse each tuple as you wish:

```
for name, caste in zip(names, castes):
    print('Hello', name.title(), caste.title())
```

This works for as many attributes as you care to specify:

```
names = 'n1 n2 n3 n4'.split()
castes = 'c1 c2 c3 c4'.split()
towns = 't1 t2 t3 t4'.split()
for name, caste, town in zip(names, castes, towns):
    print(f'{name} ({caste}) lives in {town}.')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over two lists simultaneously:

```
names = ['name1','name2','name99'] 
castes = ['cast1','cast2','cast99']

for x, y in zip(names, castes):
    print(f'Hello {x} {y}')

# Hello name1 cast1
# Hello name2 cast2                                        
# Hello name99 cast99
```

This can be done without `zip()` with just one loop. **Problem** with your approach is you used one loop inside other so the inner one repeats as many times as the outer specifies.

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(f'Hello {names[i]} {castes[i]}')
```